# Something in my initiation is causing the app to crash. I'm fresh out of ideas if anyone can help I will be greatfull

Tags: java, android

The catlog says that the first for cycle completes and the crash happens at the second one.
This is the `init` method for a very simple game.

```
private void init()

{

            Resources res = this.getResources();


            int x=R.drawable.crystal0000;
            for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)// This for completes
            {
                Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, x+i);
                Log.d("crystalframes loaded", Integer.toString(i));
                crystalframes[i]=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 20, 20, false);
            }// Nothing after this points goes trough 
             x = R.drawable.frame0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Bitmap t = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, x + i);
                Log.d("frame", Integer.toString(i));
                frames[i] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(t, 40, 40, false);
            }
            x = R.drawable.rframe0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Bitmap t = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, x + i);
                Log.d("frame", Integer.toString(i));
                frames[i + 10] = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(t, 40, 40, false);
            }
            // Code continues from the here but the crash is caused somewhere
```

in these lines

Comment: `crash happens` then add logcat here...

Comment: Is `crystalframes` big enough? Is `b` valid?

Comment: crystalframes is big enough yes.

Comment: What do you mean to add the logcat after the crash ? I'm kinda new to the android

Answer (score 1):

Probably you created `crystalframes` like this:

```
crystalframes = new Bitmap[100];
```

But you need size of 101, because you did:

```
for(int i=0;i<=100;i++)// This for completes
```

Also you could be running out of memory.

Comment: You are right omg how could I have been so stupid. thanks very much I love this site

Comment: ``OutOfMemoryException`` seems like a good call (apart from the miscalculated indices).